# windows 7 sometimes resizes and moves open windows after having hibernated or switched to and from another user

Tags: windows-7, resolution, hibernate

**Context:**

I have a desktop computer running Windows 7, an AMD HD7850 as its GPU and an Acer K272HUL QHD monitor. The monitor has been connected through DL-DVI-D and is now connected through DisplayPort, with no difference in behaviour between the two ways of connecting.

The computer is not part of an AD-domain; it is locally managed. It is however frequently used by two users who each have their own account.

**Problem:**

Sometimes (meaning that it happens, but not consistently) after I was using my account and then locked it to either put it to sleep (suspend to disk or 'hibernation') or let the other user use its account, when I log in again, I find that my open windows have been resized and moved to exactly fit a desktop resolution of 2132x1200, even though the resolution of my (only) monitor is QHD, which is 2560x1440.

This doesn't seem to happen (so far) when just locking and unlocking my currently logged in account; it has to be switched or the computer must be suspended to disk before the problem occurs.

**So far:**

I have looked for a solution to this problem multiple times, but I never found it.

The only thing that I've tried so far is [this tip posted by Jeff.Ward](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-resizes-my-open-programs-when-waking/44354708-a75e-46ff-af63-6524996e5898?page=1), but it never fixed my problem.

The biggest problem is that I don't find a lot on this subject on the internet; or at least I'm having trouble defining it properly in a search engine.